# Puedo enviar informacion de una imagen en s3 usando express?

Tags: nodejs, express, aws, amazon-s3

Se puede enviar una imagen por medio de express?
Tengo mi proyecto que muestra imagenes de un bucket privado para mostrarlas en mi frontend por medio de la etiqueta img, lo que quiero hacer es pedir mi imagen al backend enviandole tambien un jwt de verificacion y mandar mediante el backend la imagen de la forma que yo solo tenga que poner en mi frontend

```
<img src="http://localhost:8080/img/imagen.png"/>
```

Y que mi backen retorne con la imagen.

Estoy usando la libreria de `@aws-sdk/client-s3` desde mi backend para obtener la imagen, del siguiente modo:

```
const comand = new GetObjectCommand({
    Bucket: config.BUCKET,
    Key:key,
})
const result = await cli.send(comand);
```

Se que en result hay un Body, que ese es el que mando la cuestion en si es que no se como mandarlo por medio de express, eso es lo que quiero saber, tambien, si estoy haciendo mal la forma me pueden indicar cual seria el metodo correcto para hacerlo

Comment: Te doy una idea, en vez de que la comunicación sea Cliente -> express -> AWS S3 -> express -> Cliente... porque no mejor generas un `preSignedUrl` de esa imagen, de esa manera aunque la imagen sea privada podrás acceder a ella durante un corto periodo de tiempo usando la `preSignedUrl` en el cliente

Comment: Gracias, lo acabo de implementar y me funciono bien

Comment: Con mucho gusto.